# How to write async linq

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have this query:

```
public static class myClass
{ 

    list<something> myList = new list<something>();

    public void PopulateList()
    {
        var myQuery = from a in db.something
              where a.someproperty == somevar
              select a;   

        myList  = myQuery.Tolist();
    }
}
```

How can i do to make this query async?

Comment: `await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => PopulateList());` :)

Comment: No need to await on it :P

Comment: @LewsTherin Tks, but my needs are to start this query every X time automatically and it return a long list.

Comment: Weird, your void method says otherwise.

Comment: @LewsTherin You are right, maybe my sample doesn´t expalin enough

Comment: @I4V Maybe do you have a link to a completa sample?

Comment: @LewsTherin `No need to await on it` How do you know it. Maybe OP wants to make an update on UI after it is executed...

Comment: @JuanPabloGomez it is complete. It creates a task and awaits it without blocking the current thread...

Comment: @I4V I'm newer in async things, and looking for In context sample. I'm going to web search a lot for Task.Factory. Tks in advance.

Comment: @JuanPabloGomez Please do. This is the way to learn things...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35237/discussion-between-juan-pablo-gomez-and-i4v)

Comment: @l4V because it is a void method. If it returned Task, maybe.. but that's also a void method.

Comment: @LewsTherin `Task.Factory.StartNew` returns **Task** which is awaitable..

Comment: @I4V You have the reason, just post it as an answer. It works great.

Comment: @l4v I know, but I think there is no point. The `Task` itself doesn't return data. So why wait? Just let the calling thread do some other shiz.

Comment: @l4V If you can tell me why there is a point on waiting for a Task instwead of a Task<T> I will be glad. Always eager to learn new things :)

Comment: @LewsTherin I would be glad to teach you something :) first read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18193303/how-can-i-send-email-one-after-one-in-a-row) question and its answer, then [this continuation question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18194062/how-do-i-make-that-it-will-send-the-email-only-once). It should give you an example of the usage of *await Task*

Comment: @I4V Why you don't post the answer? please post it to make this question answered. TKS for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Poor man's async/await

```
await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => PopulateList());
```

**EDIT**

For those who want to see the usage of it

[How can i send email one after one in a row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18193303/how-can-i-send-email-one-after-one-in-a-row)  and its follow-up question

[How do i make that it will send the email only once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18194062/how-do-i-make-that-it-will-send-the-email-only-once)

Comment: Why `await` it?  If you want a task that does that you just need `StartNew` and you can return the task directly.  Adding `async` makes it more expensive and adds nothing.

Comment: @Servy I knew that  a jerk would downvote this answer. If you read the comments Juan asked for that many times (BTW Read the comments between me and  Lews Therin)...

Comment: I have, and you have already been told in comments why doing this isn't a good idea.  That someone else wants you to post this as an answer doesn't make it a good answer, nor one that shouldn't be downvoted.  If you had posted a quality answer with a desirable solution then perhaps you wouldn't get downvoted.  FYI, insulting other people for constructively critiquing your answers is going to increase the likelihood of you getting downvotes, rather than reducing it.

Answer (score -2):

Actually more effective async return will be:

```
await Task.FromResult(PopulateList());
```

This code returns already finished Task that is optimized for methods where you need to convert synchronous code to asynchronous.

You also need to change return type from void to Task.

Source: [Async in ASP.NET](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/aspConf/aspConf/Async-in-ASP-NET) at aspConf 2012

Comment: This is then doing all of the work synchronously, not asynchronously.