# How do i make that it will send the email only once?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void timer4_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     se.SendPhotos(photofilesDir + "\\" + "photofiles.zip");

     if (se.photossendended == true)
     {
           se.photossendended = false;
           timer4.Enabled = false;
           timer5.Enabled = true;
     }
}
```

Until `se.photossendended == true` it will keep make the `se.SendPhotos(photofilesDir + "\\" + "photofiles.zip");`

But i want it to do it once only and the keep check for the `se.photossendended` if its true.
So i tried to do `while(true)`

```
private void timer4_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     se.SendPhotos(photofilesDir + "\\" + "photofiles.zip");

     while(true)
     {
          if (se.photossendended == true)
          {
               se.photossendended = false;
               timer4.Enabled = false;
               timer5.Enabled = true;
          }
     }
}
```

But then it will hold all the program and will never make it true since the program is not continue and its all stuck in this loop.
So its never true and the loop will keep forever.

EDIT**

This is the se class SendEmail

```
public void SendPhotos(string fileNameToSend) 
        {
            try
            {
                MailAddress from = new MailAddress("username", "User " + (char)0xD8 + " Name",
                System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
                MailAddress to = new MailAddress("myrmail");
                photosmessage = new MailMessage(from, to);
                photosmessage.Body = "Please check the log file attachment i have some bugs.";
                string someArrows = new string(new char[] { '\u2190', '\u2191', '\u2192', '\u2193' });
                photosmessage.Body += Environment.NewLine + someArrows;
                photosmessage.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                photosmessage.Subject = "Log File For Checking Bugs" + someArrows;
                photosmessage.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                Attachment myAttachment = new Attachment(fileNameToSend, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
                photosmessage.Attachments.Add(myAttachment);
                SmtpClient photossend = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
                photossend.SendCompleted += new SendCompletedEventHandler(photossend_SendCompleted);
                photossend.EnableSsl = true;
                photossend.Timeout = 10000;
                photossend.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                photossend.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                photossend.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass");
                string userState = "test message1";
                photossend.SendAsync(photosmessage, userState);
                SendLogFile.Enabled = false;
            }

            catch (Exception errors)
            {
                Logger.Write("Error sending message :" + errors);
            }
        }

        private void photossend_SendCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            photosmessage.Dispose();
            photossendended = true;
        }
```

I wanted to make sure the email sent so i did that it will be true: photossendended = true;
Then in Form1 in timer4 tick event i want to send the email once if its true stop the timer activate timer 5 then send there the second email and over and over again.

I have 4 timers tick events i diasble and enable them one by one.
The reason is that i wanted to send each email only when the one before had finished to be sent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you are trying to send mails async without blocking the UI, but want also to wait till sending is completed before continuing with next mail.

If you are using c#5/.Net 4.5 You can use `SendMailAsync` in an [`async`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx) method as:

```
async void SendMails()
{
    await server.SendMailAsync(mailMessage1);
    await server.SendMailAsync(mailMessage2);
}
```

So, your method can be something like this

```
public Task SendPhotos(string fileNameToSend)
{
    try
    {
        MailAddress from = new MailAddress("username", "User " + (char)0xD8 + " Name", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
        MailAddress to = new MailAddress("myrmail");
        var photosmessage = new MailMessage(from, to);
        photosmessage.Body = "Please check the log file attachment i have some bugs.";
        string someArrows = new string(new char[] { '\u2190', '\u2191', '\u2192', '\u2193' });
        photosmessage.Body += Environment.NewLine + someArrows;
        photosmessage.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        photosmessage.Subject = "Log File For Checking Bugs" + someArrows;
        photosmessage.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        Attachment myAttachment = new Attachment(fileNameToSend, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
        photosmessage.Attachments.Add(myAttachment);
        SmtpClient photossend = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
        photossend.EnableSsl = true;
        photossend.Timeout = 10000;
        photossend.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        photossend.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        photossend.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass");
        SendLogFile.Enabled = false;
        return photossend.SendMailAsync(photosmessage);
    }
    catch (Exception errors)
    {
        Logger.Write("Error sending message :" + errors);
        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }
}
```

and you can use it

```
await se.SendPhotos(photofilesDir1 + "\\" + "photofiles.zip");
await se.SendPhotos(photofilesDir2 + "\\" + "photofiles.zip");
```

*PS: Now a better name for your method would be `SendPhotosAsync`*

Answer (score 2):

```
private void timer4_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!se.photossendended)
    {
        se.SendPhotos(photofilesDir + "\\" + "photofiles.zip");
        se.photossendended = true;
        timer4.Enabled = false;
        timer5.Enabled = true;
    }            
}
```

It looks like that you want to send email asynchronously. You have almost done with the code in `photossend_SendCompleted`. The remaining code should be as follow:

```
bool sendingStarted;
private void timer4_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if(!sendingStarted) {
         se.SendPhotos(photofilesDir + "\\" + "photofiles.zip");
         sendingStarted = true;
     }
     if(photossended){
       timer4.Enabled = false;
       timer5.Enabled = true;   
    }            
}
```

I think you should expose the event `SendCompleted` of the class `SendEmail` so that we can do something like this:

```
se.SendCompleted += (s,e) => {
    timer4.Enabled = false;
    timer5.Enabled = true;//Of course we still need the flag sendingStarted.
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what `se.SendPhotos` looks like but you could do it like this

```
private void timer4_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     se.SendPhotos(photofilesDir + "\\" + "photofiles.zip");

     while(true)
     {
          if (se.photossendended == true)
          {
               se.photossendended = false;
               timer4.Enabled = false;
               timer5.Enabled = true;
               break;
          }
     }
}
```

But this is more a hack than a solution :/

Comment: I do not think this is what he is trying to do. The next time timer4 ticks, it will send the photos again, even though he wants it to stop once `se.photosendended` is true.

Comment: Yeah, that was my second thought... BUt he didn't really write much info so I guess this is a good start :D

Comment: updated my question. in general i cant find yet how to send 4 email one after one. i need to make sure the email sent and only then to send the next one. before using timers i added all the email to be send in backgroundworker do work event but then it sent all the emails at once without even waiting for the one before to finish.