# How to send async email with file from file system?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I have situation where I am sending an email with image as LinkedResource.

I have used the ImageStream to read the file and it works.

### The problem :

when the response arrive to the client it first try to access to this image but because I have sent the email async and it didnt finished the sending I am getting an error that file cant be access.

### Is there any better way to do that ?

```
FileStream ImageStream = new FileStream(QRPath, FileMode.Open);
 System.Net.Mail.LinkedResource imageResource = new System.Net.Mail.LinkedResource(ImageStream, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);
 imageResource.ContentId = "AttchImg";
                htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(imageResource);
SendMail(EmailMessage,true);


private void SendMail(MailMessage EmailMessage,bool IsAsync)
    {
        string FromEmail = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["EmailSender"];
        string FromPassword = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["EmailSenderPass"];
        EmailMessage.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(FromEmail);
        if (IsAsync)
        {
            try
            {
                AsyncMethodCaller caller = new AsyncMethodCaller(SendMailInSeperateThread);
                AsyncCallback callbackHandler = new AsyncCallback(AsyncCallback);
                caller.BeginInvoke(EmailMessage, callbackHandler, null);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Logging
            }
        }
        else
        {
            SmtpClient smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
            smtp.Host = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["EmailSenderSmtpHost"];
            smtp.Port = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["Port"]);//;587;
            //For google use smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(FromEmail, FromPassword);
            smtp.Timeout = 20000;
            smtp.Send(EmailMessage);
        }
    }


    private void SendMailInSeperateThread(MailMessage message)
    {
        try
        {
            SmtpClient smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
            smtp.Host = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["EmailSenderSmtpHost"];
            smtp.Port = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["Port"]);//;587;
            //For google use smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            string FromEmail = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["EmailSender"];
            string FromPassword = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["EmailSenderPass"];

            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(FromEmail, FromPassword);
            smtp.Timeout = 20000;
            smtp.Send(message);

            //smtp.Dispose();
            //message.AlternateViews[0].LinkedResources.Dispose();
            //message.AlternateViews[1].LinkedResources.Dispose();
            //message.Dispose();

            // If you have a flag checking to see if an email was sent, set it here
            // Pass more parameters in the delegate if you need to...
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // This is very necessary to catch errors since we are in
            // a different context & thread
            //Elmah.ErrorLog.GetDefault(null).Log(new Error(e));
        }
    }

    private void AsyncCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            AsyncResult result = (AsyncResult)ar;
            AsyncMethodCaller caller = (AsyncMethodCaller)result.AsyncDelegate;
            caller.EndInvoke(ar);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //Elmah.ErrorLog.GetDefault(null).Log(new Error(e));
            //Elmah.ErrorLog.GetDefault(null).Log(new Error(new Exception("Emailer - This hacky asynccallback thing is puking, serves you right.")));
        }
    }
```

---

I just found that you can do that :

LinkedResource imageResource = new LinkedResource("C:\myImage.png", "image/jpg");

is it better way then Sriram Sakthivel wrote  ???

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18194062/how-do-i-make-that-it-will-send-the-email-only-once) may help

Answer (score 0):

Try using one of the other FileStream overloads.

```
FileStream ImageStream = new FileStream(QRPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
```